# Setting up a virtual machine for Udacity

Tags: virtual-machine

I keep getting this error when setting up VM for intro to programming nano degree for udacity:

```
$ cd Downloads/FSND-Virtual-Machine 
bash: cd: Downloads/FSND-Virtual-Machine: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you provide more context. How are you setting up the VM. which cloud which steps you followed? What did you download ?

Comment: this is a default linux commandline error that tells you, that the directory. FSND-Virtual-Machine is not in the directory Downloads.